# node-red temperature based light or fan

Tags: javascript, raspberry-pi, iot, node-red

i am retrieving temperature value from sensor into a function. how can i turn something On or Off connected to raspberry pin via toggle switch. tried if else in function but it wouldn't return Boolean.

Comment: Please give us more details about your problem, like pasting some code.

Comment: What have you already tried, Node-RED on the pi comes with GPIO nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this flow can help you out... :)

[node-red flow overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VoCtj.png)

```html
[{"id":"b91e3004.20d918","type":"inject","z":"96584deb.e06cd8","name":"temperature = 5","topic":"","payload":"5","payloadType":"num","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"x":240,"y":480,"wires":[["8ed1e022.82aef8","90a9aef0.51dda"]]},{"id":"8ed1e022.82aef8","type":"function","z":"96584deb.e06cd8","name":"temp >= 10","func":"\nmsg.payload = (msg.payload >= 10);\n\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"noerr":0,"x":490,"y":460,"wires":[["b639cd87.885478","e13b38f4.0af918"]]},{"id":"b639cd87.885478","type":"debug","z":"96584deb.e06cd8","name":"","active":true,"tosidebar":true,"console":false,"tostatus":false,"complete":"false","x":670,"y":440,"wires":[]},{"id":"c44cdc90.fc2388","type":"inject","z":"96584deb.e06cd8","name":"temperature = 20","topic":"","payload":"20","payloadType":"num","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"onceDelay":0.1,"x":240,"y":540,"wires":[["8ed1e022.82aef8","90a9aef0.51dda"]]},{"id":"e13b38f4.0af918","type":"rpi-gpio out","z":"96584deb.e06cd8","name":"","pin":"7","set":"","level":"0","freq":"","out":"out","x":650,"y":480,"wires":[]},{"id":"90a9aef0.51dda","type":"switch","z":"96584deb.e06cd8","name":"temp >= 10","property":"payload","propertyType":"msg","rules":[{"t":"gte","v":"10","vt":"str"},{"t":"lt","v":"10","vt":"str"}],"checkall":"true","repair":false,"outputs":2,"x":490,"y":560,"wires":[["72eff73c.7845b"],["268e12dd.9e100e"]]},{"id":"72eff73c.7845b","type":"template","z":"96584deb.e06cd8","name":"true","field":"payload","fieldType":"msg","format":"handlebars","syntax":"mustache","template":"true","output":"str","x":650,"y":540,"wires":[["28a0b8f8.67062"]]},{"id":"28a0b8f8.67062","type":"rpi-gpio out","z":"96584deb.e06cd8","name":"","pin":"7","set":"","level":"0","freq":"","out":"out","x":790,"y":560,"wires":[]},{"id":"268e12dd.9e100e","type":"template","z":"96584deb.e06cd8","name":"false","field":"payload","fieldType":"msg","format":"handlebars","syntax":"mustache","template":"false","output":"str","x":650,"y":580,"wires":[["28a0b8f8.67062"]]}]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, when you reply to a question, try to explain your answer, not just exposed.